# mod_rewrite in Virtual Hosting For Reverse Proxy

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I'm using Tomcat on port 8080 behind Apache 2.4 on port 443. I've setup the usual reverse proxy configuration on Apache virtual host which is working okay. This is my setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http:example.com:8080/
    <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/CA.crt

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    RewriteRule ^post$ post.xhtml [NC]
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to use mod_rewrite on Apache, however, this seems not to be working. I realized that when doing rewrite on .htaccess (which is not applicable in my case), the rewrite rules work okay. However, when I try the same rule from the virtual host, it is not working. For example, using the rule below:

```
RewriteEngine on
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
RewriteRule ^test$ test.php [QSA]
```

I get the 404 error with the following from the error logs:

```
[Tue Aug 14 12:12:40.135059 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 11554] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:53326] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7efc776e9518][rid#7efc776710a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test
[Tue Aug 14 12:12:40.135108 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 11554] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:53326] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7efc776e9518][rid#7efc776710a0/initial] applying pattern '^test$' to uri '/test'
[Tue Aug 14 12:12:40.135121 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 11554] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:53326] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7efc776e9518][rid#7efc776710a0/initial] pass through /test
```

What could be missing? I wish it were possible to do rewrite rule on .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution; first of all, .htaccess does not apply. According to the documentation, *server config* and *virtual host* are the context for mod_proxy that apply (.htaccess in our case doesn't make sense anyway).

The solution is to use a rewrite rule with the flag P, which causes the request to be handled by mod_proxy, and handled via a proxy request. See more [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

The virtual host should be modified as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/post/(.*)$ post.xhtml\?id=$1 [P]
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http:example.com:8080/
```